# Removing specific parts of a string c#

Tags: c#

> ANS680401571E0001(FreeEntry-ControlledExit)01930F0003(InService)019423Gate Interface Controller 173(0XAD)019545G.I.C(1014028) EntryValidator(01.00.14028) ExitValidator(01.00.14028)53

Everything before the first "(" needs to be removed. There is no rule as to how long this part can be(it differs). Then after ")" everything needs to be removed EXCEPT for the last 4 characters before the next "(" ,in this case 0003 needs to stay. Also note that the 01930F can change and the length will also change. Next every between after the "(InService)" and "Gate" has to be removed. and last everything after "ExitValidator(01.00.14028)" has to be removed.

This is basically what it needs to look like once done.

(FreeEntry-ControlledExit)
0003(InService)
Gate Interface Controller 173(0XAD)
G.I.C(1014028)
EntryValidator(01.00.14028)
ExitValidator(01.00.14028)

Comment: What logical rules dictate *what* text is removed? i.e. why does 01930F0003 become 0003 and so on?

Comment: what did you tried already? how do you know what text should be removed? Sound like an (btw. unsolvable) "Give me teh codez" to me.

Comment: @MischaBehrend that's spelled "Gimme teh codez".

Comment: oops... my mistake... I can't edit it :(

Comment: 0003 is associated with the (in service), it an operational mode for the equipment. The 01930F is something our back office uses, not sure what for as I am developing an app to take over the back office when there is no network.

Comment: I currently am using substrings and str.Replace to remove the strings. Looking for a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution for that but I would start with making some method to substring your whole input string like such :

```
string p(string input, string openSign, string closeSign, ref int sPos, int lOffset = 0, int rOffset = 0)
{
    int idxL = input.IndexOf(openSign, sPos);
    int idxR = input.IndexOf(closeSign, idxL);
    sPos = idxL + 1;
    if(idxL != -1 && idxR != -1)
    {
        int s = idxL - lOffset;
        int e = idxR + 1 + rOffset;
        return input.Substring(s, e - s);
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Then you can make use it like such :

```
string input = "ANS680401571E0001(FreeEntry-ControlledExit)01930F0003(InService)019423Gate Interface Controller 173(0XAD)019545G.I.C(1014028) EntryValidator(01.00.14028) ExitValidator(01.00.14028)53";
string build = "";

build = "";

int i = 0;
build += p(input, "(", ")", ref i, 0, 0);
build += p(input, "(", ")", ref i, 4, 0);
build += p(input, "Gate", ")", ref i, 0, 0);
build += p(input, "G.I.C", ")", ref i, 0, 0);
build += p(input, "Entry", ")", ref i, 0, 0);
build += p(input, "Exit", ")", ref i, 0, 0);
```

Which will result with build being >> `"(FreeEntry-ControlledExit)0003(InService)Gate Interface Controller 173(0XAD)G.I.C(1014028)EntryValidator(01.00.14028)ExitValidator(01.00.14028)"`

[Online example](http://rextester.com/QGYNZ14625)

---

This should be possible with regular expressions but I don't have time now to think about that. Maybe I'll update my answer later on when there will be no sufficient answer.